How to connect paddle with sveltekit
I am trying to add paddle with sveltekit but I'm stuck with 400 error, I did search on google, read the documentation but I still couldn't understand what am I doing wrong?
I know paddle gives production and sandbox option, and I am trying my test on sandbox.
I just couldn't see the checkout box ,
this is what the alert box says:
Something went wrong
Please try again later. If the issue persists, you can contact our support team using the button below.

this is what the console is giving me:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Here what I've come up with.
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import { initializePaddle, type Paddle } from '@paddle/paddle-js';
import { PADDLE_CLIENT_API, PADDLE_PRICE_ID } from '$lib';

let paddlePriceId = [{ priceId: PADDLE_PRICE_ID, quantity: 1 }];
let paddle: Paddle;

onMount(async () => {
    const paddleInstance = await initializePaddle({
        environment: 'sandbox',
        token: `${PADDLE_CLIENT_API}`
    });
    if (paddleInstance) {
        paddle = paddleInstance;
    }
});

const startCheckout = async () => {
    try {
    await paddle?.Checkout.open({
        settings: {
            displayMode: 'overlay',
            theme: 'light',
            locale: 'en'
        },
        items: paddlePriceId
    });
}  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error opening checkout:', error);
    // Handle the error, e.g., display an error message to the user
}

};


If you get back a status code of 400, then it means that something is wrong with the request that was sent. To learn what was wrong, one can usually read the body of the response. So in your web browser's Developers Console's Network tab, find the request/response, and see what the body of the response says.

@PeppeL-G the error there is: "details": "Failed to retrieve JWT"

What does PADDLE_CLIENT_API contain? Did you create the token as described in the docs?

I figure it out, the problem was in the paddle_price_id, I was passing product ID in it not actual price_id, I got one more question I could not find it out in the docs, can we add a custom detail field in paddle checkout? theres an option of custom_data but its not displaying on the checkout
